# log4j move rolling files to another directory/location

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

my goal is whenever file `mylog.log` is rolled to `mylog.log.1` this rolled file is also moved to another directory, so in the original directory there is always only `mylog.log`. Is this possible using `RollingFileAppender`? Or another appender from default `log4j` library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the `RollingFileAppender` from Log4J

if you use version >= 1.2.16 and the log4j-extras you can use this

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, base
log4j.appender.base=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.base.File=/tmp/logger.log
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
log4j.appender.base.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.base.triggeringPolicy.maxFileSize=100
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/tmp/logger-%i.log
log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/tmp/test/logger-%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.base.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.base.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The important part is `log4j.appender.base.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/tmp/test/logger-%i.log.gz`

But you have to make sure that the folder (in this example `/tmp/test` exists

Comment: Why the minimum requirement is the 1.2.16 version ?