# Log4j DailyRollingFileAppender: Specifying rollover directory

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Does anyone happen to know if log4j's DailyRollingFileAppender class is capable of creating the new logs in a different directory than the source file?

I know that this is possible with RollingFileAppender, as per:
[log4j move rolling files to another directory/location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866704/log4j-move-rolling-files-to-another-directory-location)

The reason I would like to use the former appender is because it enables the rollover process to be based on a date or time, as opposed to a maximum file size.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, EXAMPLE

log4j.appender.EXAMPLE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.File=/path/to/my/logs/example.log
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.Append=true
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %X{userId} - %X{sessionId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: You can extend dailyrollingfileappender and implement your own rollover() method which uses a different rollover location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one way to create the rolled logs in a different directory (although it is a bit of a fudge and very limiting in terms of the directory name and location).

Since the `DatePattern` appends the pattern to the end of the log file name, you can do something like this:

```
log4j.appender.EXAMPLE.DatePattern='_old/example.log.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

which will lead to the finished logs ending up in the directory like :-
 `/path/to/my/logs/example.log_old`

Comment: Sorry, but would this not lead to rollover files called: **example.log_old/example.log.yyyy-MM-dd**?

Since **'.'yyyy-MM-dd** results in **example.log.yyyy-MM-dd** I mean.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. As I said, it's very limiting - the directory that the files will go into will be inside the directory that the actual log file is in, and the name of the directory will have to start with **example.log**

Comment: Right sorry I can see what you mean now - got a bit confused yesterday. Thank you, however it looks as if I will instead be relying on a shell script for the purpose of creating archived logs. DailyRollingFileAppender does not seem trustworthy enough as some people are reporting issues with the rollover operation. (Something I got a taste of myself yesterday.) For example: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21528617

Answer (score 0):

Find below code where you can archive it very easy way, kindly check and revert 
  [Reference](http://2min2code.com/articles/log4j_intro/rolling_archiving_file_per_day_prop)

```
#Worked with 2.17 version
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, app
log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.app.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.app.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=worker.log
log4j.appender.app.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=worker-.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
log4j.appender.app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```