# log4j appending location in Application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j

I want to append the log files which exceeds 10 MB file size in a separate folder.
Ex - folder inside the logging folder called /info/___.zip

can I do it using just application. properties file in spring boot? without using logback.xml?

```
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO

logging.file=/logs/sup/${log.name}-info.log
```

Comment: you can try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41594486/7417402

Comment: I am not sure whether you can do without logback.xml but another alternative  would you like to run a cronjob to rotate the logs?

Comment: you can try with `RollingFileAppender`...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866704/log4j-move-rolling-files-to-another-directory-location